# Xamarin.forms label content getting null from deserialized var

Tags: c#, rest, post, xamarin.forms, httprequest

I'm trying to create a simple mobile app that just POST to an external REST api page that I get some data from the response but I'm stuck because I get the data from the site but when I want to run it the data of the **deserialized** var is getting null.

This is my code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.zivali.net/api/PageSearchApi/AdvancedSearch");//site for the rest api

        var postData = "{SectionID: 1,PageNumber: 1,PageSize: 1}"; //sending parameter
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST"; //method
        request.ContentType = "application/json"; //content type
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        var Podatki = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<zivaliii>(responseString);
    }
}
```

This is the `zivaliii` class its generated with `http://json2csharp.com/`

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/ed109okvwf5vp5x/zivali.json?dl=0` the json file

```
public class zivaliii
{
     public class Customer
     {
         public int TotalCount { get; set; }
         public bool TaxObligatory { get; set; }
         public bool Active { get; set; }
         public bool Deleted { get; set; }
         public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
         public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
         public bool IsCompany { get; set; }
         public int CountryId { get; set; }
         public int RegionId { get; set; }
         public int PostId { get; set; }
         public int MembershipId { get; set; }
         public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }
         public int DesiredCustomerTypeId { get; set; }
         public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
         public int ArticleId { get; set; }
         public bool NewsletterSignUp { get; set; }
         public int RecordId { get; set; }
     }

     public class CountryCategory
     {
         public int CategoryId { get; set; }
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public bool Deleted { get; set; }
         public string SeoId { get; set; }
         public string SeoKeywords { get; set; }
         public int CountryId { get; set; }
         public int RecordId { get; set; }
     }

     public class Breadcrumb
     {
         public string MasterKey { get; set; }
         public int ParentId { get; set; }
         public List<CountryCategory> CountryCategories { get;   set; }
         public string SearchString { get; set; }
         public int RecordId { get; set; }
     }

     public class Advertisement
     {
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public string SeoId { get; set; }
         public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
         public string FullDescription { get; set; }
         public int Price { get; set; }
         public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
         public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
         public bool Deleted { get; set; }
         public bool IsActive { get; set; }
         public bool IsPedigree { get; set; }
         public int Age { get; set; }
         public bool IsPayable { get; set; }
         public bool IsExposed { get; set; }
         public bool IsUsed { get; set; }
         public Customer Customer { get; set; }
         public int CustomerFK { get; set; }
         public int CategoryFK { get; set; }
         public int RegionFK { get; set; }
         public List<object> Pictures { get; set; }
         public List<Breadcrumb> Breadcrumbs { get; set; }
         public int TotalCount { get; set; }
         public bool PriceByAgreement { get; set; }
         public string DefaultCountry { get; set; }
         public int RecordId { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }
        public int AdvertisementTotalCount { get; set; }
        public int AdvertisementMinPrice { get; set; }
        public int AdvertisementMaxPrice { get; set; }
        public List<object> Customers { get; set; }
        public int CustomerTotalCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: Problem]

The problem is here because I want to display the name parameter.

I'm a beginner at this so any help would be appreciated. :)

Best regards, kona

Comment: Is var Podatki null? Also would be nice to know what the JSON looks like, and also the shape of zivaliii

Comment: @Phil i updated the question with your requests

Comment: your json contains an array of Advertisements, not a single Advertisement.

Comment: @Jason Actually made some modifications before and it works now but dont know how do i call Name from Advertisements

Comment: you need to specify an index: Advertisements[0].Name

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the helping me :)